# Dell Vostro 5470 Low audio

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a Dell Vostro 5470 notebook. It has three speakers. Two normal and one subwoofer. The subwoofer is not working under elementary os or ubuntu. Windows uses the MaxxAudio 4. Can you help me to fix this problem, please.

Thank you,
Kind regards,
Tamas Racz

Comment: open a terminal and write `alsamixer`, press enter and press F3. Then turn everything up and disable the mute (so that you don't see MM and you only see oo). Does it work now?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answear. But it's not working. I mean yeah, but no. So I think the subwoofer is working just the sound is not the best. Like a worst sound. Not as good as windows. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: I have three of that what you said. But every three are oo.

Comment: Try to know which one is the subwoofer and put it to a medium level.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not the best. The audio quality is not acceptable. :(

Comment: I'm going to create an answer with a possible solution, try that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following at the end of the file:

```
sudo pantheon-text-editor /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf

[Mapping analog-surround-21]
device-strings = surround21:%f
channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe
vpaths-output = analog-output analog-output-lineout analog-output-speaker analog-output-desktop-speaker
priority = 10
direction = output


sudo pantheon-text-editor /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common

[Element PCM]
switch = on
volume = ignore
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

Then create this file and add that one line.

```
pantheon-text-editor ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf

enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```

Now install this packages `sudo apt install cmt blop ladspa-gtk`

Lastly, you need to create this file but now you'll have to change `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo-21` to the output of `pactl list sinks | grep Name` (Omiting the "Name" word). If you have more than one, ask me first.

```
~/.config/pulse/default.pa

load-module module-ladspa-sink  sink_name=ladspa_low_pass master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo-21 plugin=lp4pole_1671 label=lp4pole_fcrcia_oa control=200,0
load-module module-remap-sink   sink_name=remapLFE        master=ladspa_low_pass                               remix=no   channels=1 master_channel_map=lfe                    channel_map=lfe
load-module module-remap-sink   sink_name=remap20         master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo-21 remix=no   channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combine         slaves=remap20,remapLFE                                         channels=3                                           channel_map=front-left,front-right,lfe
set-default-sink combine
```

---

Answer taken from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_N55SF#Audio)